# why does pandas not print entire column.values to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Apologies if this is a repeat question, I have no idea how to phrase my problem and I haven't been able to find exactly what I am looking for. I am a bit new to python and programming. Basically, I have a large dataset that I am trying to group into a row form per subject (1 to 3) per ID. It looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 I
A A A 1
T T T 1
C C C 1
...
C C A 2
T T T 2
C C C 2
...
A A A 3
G G C 3
C C C 3
...
```

except my datatable is much larger. I loaded this table into pandas with python, used the following:

```
grouped=dataframe.groupby('I')
testframe=[]
testframe.append(grouped[person].values)
test_data=DataFrame(testframe)
```

I get something that looks like I expect, but when I print it out to a CSV it only prints:

```
['G', 'T', 'T', ..., 'T', 'G', 'C']
```

how can I get it to print all the values instead of just a subset? Is there a better way to achieve what I am doing. The overall output is correct, i just need every element, not this shortened version. How can I achieve this?

-edit- to add clarity in what i mean..
so for example:
`len(test_data[0]['SomeGeneID'])
output: 2571 and prints the truncated list
len(test_data[0]['DifferentgeneID'])
output: 879 and prints entire list`
I guess my question is why is this happening, how can I prevent it, and is there a better way to achieve my goals than pandas?

Comment: What way do you "print it out to a CSV"?

Comment: You won't be able to access groupby `values` in 0.13, I'm not sure what you think it is...

Comment: I use test_data.to_csv('whatever.csv') and I look at the cells, basically the ID numbers with less than 1000 values tend to print entirely, but not ones larger. I'm not really sure what I'm doing,what do you mean access groupby values? I see them in my testframe list, it's just elipsied off like 0: N,N,N...

Comment: @user2963701 this bit: `grouped[person].values` raises in 0.13rc.

Comment: hmm.. well I definitely get the column values using that command.. is that why its truncating though?

Comment: @AndyHayden I don't have 0.13 yet, on 0.12 code works fine, althrough returns Series instead of expected numpy structures.

Comment: @alko yeah, it "works" but is undocumented/unsupported and won't work after upgrading - at whatever time in the future!

Answer (score 0):

For 0.12 code works, and `grouped[person].values` is a Series with index from `dataframe['I']` distinct values and arrays of `dataframe[person]` corresponding items.

You resulting dataframe then contains one column of datatype object, and it is stored in csv with its representation, which ellipsises long arrays.

To be preceise, your resulting dataframe in general can't be a proper csv, as different rows may have different lenghts. In case groups have length not greater than `l`, you can try something like `pd.DataFrame(map(list, grouped[person].values))` to make it a DataFrame with `l` columns, with `None`'s for missing values (shorter rows).

Comment: thanks for your input. i'll try that tomorrow morning and let you know!

Comment: I don't think you should be advocating that people use `grouped[person].values`... why not just use `dataframe[person].values` ?

Comment: @AndyHayden guess you're right. probably, if you can, you'd better post a proper answer and I'll delete this one. Being pretty busy atm, have no time to elaborate correct approach.

Comment: if i used dataframe[person].values i also get the truncated array, but it returns a truncated array for the entire column, rather than per gene ID which is the ultimate goal.

Comment: thanks for the input, but I ended up using awk to accomplish this feat!